# Pusher not receiving events from Laravel 5.2 broadcasting

Tags: php, laravel-5, pusher

I am using Laravel 5.2 and php 7. I am testing this on a local Mac OSX environment. I am having no trouble pinging other services or making requests with php. I configured my application by editing broadcasting.php and .env with my api details.

broadcasting.php

```
'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),

'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('mykey'),
        'secret' => env('mysecret'),
        'app_id' => env('myappid'),
    ],
...
```

and in .env

```
...
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_KEY=mykey
PUSHER_SECRET=mysecret
PUSHER_APP_ID=myappid
...
```

I created a TestEvent like so

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'power'=> '10'
            );
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test_channel'];
    }
}
```

I then call on the event like so

```
Event::fire(new TestEvent());
```

The event shows up and is processed in redis

```
[2016-02-04 10:06:18] Processed: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent
[2016-02-04 10:08:44] Processed: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent
[2016-02-04 10:11:14] Processed: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent
[2016-02-04 10:11:59] Processed: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent
[2016-02-04 10:14:22] Processed: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent
[2016-02-04 11:17:04] Processed: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent
[2016-02-04 11:38:14] Processed: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent
```

But nothing shows up in pusher when viewing the debug console. So it seems that the event is never being sent to pusher for some reason. I also checked my timezone settings to make sure that was not an issue. There are no errors in my in the laravel log file when the event is broadcasted.

**How can I solve this problem? Is there a good way to debug and see if there is actually a request being made to pusher?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not fix the issue and maybe you changed your details for the question, but if your `.env` is like this:

```
PUSHER_KEY=mykey
PUSHER_SECRET=mysecret
PUSHER_APP_ID=myappid
```

Shouldn't the code for your pusher credentials look like this:

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    ],
```

It's referencing the value in your code, not the key!

Comment: So obvious now that I see it. This solved the problem. Will most likely mark this as the solution but will wait a few hours to allow others to answer or give input. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it's working for you now. It would be great to see some solutions on debugging such issues as I've not experimented with these features properly. I expect you may have checked, but does your log file throw anything up with regards to invalid credentials? You can find it in `/storage/logs/laravel.log` or the log with today's date. You may want to update my answer or add your own if you find the issue is showing up in your log file. Thanks.

Comment: No there is nothing in my log file, that would have made this a lot easier to solve. I had stated that towards the end of my question.

Comment: My bad I missed that, thought you may have. Hopefully someone can post up some details of how to debug such issues.

Comment: @haakym, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877837/how-can-i-make-realtime-notification-for-user-who-are-not-login